# Kendo UI Grid edit popup flickering

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui

I have to restrict some records, for that I put one condition

```
edit: function (e) { 
            if(e.model.IsReadOnly) {
                  $('#gridTiming').data("kendoGrid").closeCell(); 
            }
        },
```

But for the read-only records it's flickering. Is there any other way to restrict records.

I am using new Kendo version “v2012.3.1114″.

Comment: @troy-alford can you please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

```
$('#GridName tbody').on('click','tr',function(e){
    var grid = $(this).closest('.k-grid');
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);
    if(dataItem.IsReadOnly){
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
})
```